# How to include polymorphic association in 'includes' Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, ruby-1.8.7, meta-search

I have this in model:

```
    belongs_to :merchant_owner, :polymorphic => true
```

I want to make query like this:

```
   @search = Merchant.includes(:merchant_owner).search
   @merchants = @search.order
```

But I get this error in views:

```
 You can't create a polymorphic belongs_to join without specifying the polymorphic class!
```

for this line:

```
@search.count
```

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.20 and meta search 1.0.6. Does anyone know how to make the includes work with merchant_owner?